# Cannot connect with proxy servers using headless chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, proxy, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

| Component | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating system | win 10 |
| Node.js | 12.16.1 |
| Chrome/Chromium/... | Chrome 87 (latest), using Chrome Launcher 0.13.4 |
| chrome-remote-interface | 0.28.2 |

Is Chrome running in a container? ~~YES~~ / **NO**

Attempting to connect to webpages through a free proxy server, using sites like:

https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list

http://www.freeproxylists.net/

https://free-proxy-list.net/

For this I've been using Chrome Launcher to set up the headless chrome instance, and then some really basic chrome remote interface stuff to test that the IP address has changed. I'm checking my IP address of the headless chrome instance using this website https://whatismyipaddress.com/. Following similarly to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAyocwixpFA.

Code that I'm using to connect, use proxy and check IP:
https://hastebin.com/zogaxujori.js

In this case with and without using the chrome flag `--proxy-server=PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT`, I always retrieve my IP address, and never get the address of any of the proxy servers. I've also tried different variations of the --proxy-server option: You can find the three here https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-settings

`--proxy-server=PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT eg; (--proxy-server=255.255.255.255:8080)`

`--proxy-server=SCHEME=PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT eg; (--proxy-server=https=255.255.255.255:8080)`

`--proxy-server=LINK_TO_PROXY eg; (https://255.255.255.255:8080)`

I've tried all of these, including adding the "double quotes" around the values, and all have given me the same result, I've also tried using a random string (in attempt to get an error) for the proxy ip, and again get the same result. I'm not sure whether this is a chrome-launcher issue or a chrome-remote-interface issue either. In any case, I never receive an error from chrome-launcher or chrome-remote-interface, and the script just spits out my IP address.

Comment: i had also asked similar kind of question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65372704/puppeteer-cant-access-https-site-with-proxy-server)  but sadly no one has answered . by the way you can use http://httpbin.org/ip to get the ip address you were requesting from .

Comment: @SyntaxHacker I was able to solve this fortunatly over at https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/issues/442. In that case I used ( --proxy-server=PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT eg; (--proxy-server=255.255.255.255:8080 ) ), and some extra security certificate overiding with the chrome-remote-interface.